# Required android.gms.maps.GoogleMap found com.examle.myprojec.WorkAroundFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-scrollview

Firstly I know that getMap() method is deprecated,but still to avoid scrollview inside map I used this method:

http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-make-android-map-scrollable-inside-a-scrollview-layout/

Creating a custom fragment. But still,on that getMap() point, I don't know what to do.

Here is my custom Fragment:

```
public class WorkaroundMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private OnTouchListener mListener;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstance) {
        View layout = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, savedInstance);
        TouchableWrapper frameLayout = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return layout;
    }
    public void setListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;}
    public interface OnTouchListener {
        public abstract void onTouch();
    }
    public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {
        public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
            }
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my xml code for the mapfragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline3"
            tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity"
        class="com.example.jonida.restsapp.customFragment.WorkaroundMapFragment"/>
```

And this is my code inside onViewCreated,( I am not doing anything inside activities in this project.)

```
public class OrderDetailsActivityFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @BindView(R.id.scrollView_order_details)
    ScrollView mScrollView;

    private GoogleMap googleMap;
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        googleMap=((WorkaroundMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap //Here is my problem :/ ;
        ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).setListener(new WorkaroundMapFragment.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTouch() {
   mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);}});
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestion, thank you.

Comment: look at class="com.example.jonida.restsapp.customFragment.WorkaroundMapFragment in your fragment.

Comment: Hmm do you think there is a problem there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Required android.gms.maps.GoogleMap found com.examle.myprojec.WorkAroundFragment

from your error you need to declare your **`googleMap`** as **`WorkaroundMapFragment`** not as a **`GoogleMap`**

Use this

```
 private WorkaroundMapFragment  googleMap = (WorkaroundMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap.getMapAsync(this);


            ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.flysl_map))
                    .setListener(new WorkaroundMapFragment.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTouch() {
                            mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        }
                    });
```

Instead of this

```
googleMap=((WorkaroundMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap //Here is my problem :/ ;
        ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).setListener(new WorkaroundMapFragment.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTouch() {
   mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);}});
```

**EDIT**

```
<fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline3"
            tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity"
            class="com.example.jonida.restsapp.customFragment.WorkaroundMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOUUU

Comment: @FatjonRrapaj happy to help you

Comment: i just did :D :)